# Tensor class that has its own storage, but that can also map an external pointer

Tags: c++, c++14

I am designing a tensor class. Now I want to extend it to also be able to map (view) a pointer to some external data array (that is kept alive externally). My current approach to introduce a container (`m_container` below) and reference to it through a pointer (`m_data` below). To map I can then simply let `m_data` point outside rather than to `m_container`. The problem is that it works in any of my minimal examples, but inside the bigger code it sometimes fails (*even without using the "map"*).

I understand that this is a vague problem. That is also the reason that I cannot get my head around it. Maybe the problem is obvious to someone else?

```
class Foo
{
private:

  double m_container[2];
  double *m_data = &m_container[0];

public:

  Foo(){}

  double& operator[](size_t i) { return m_data[i]; }

  void map(double *D) { m_data = D; }

  void copy(const double *D)
  {
    for ( size_t i = 0 ; i < 2 ; ++i )
      m_data[i] = D[i];
  }
};

int main()
{
  double data[2];

  data[0] = 0.;
  data[1] = 1.;

  Foo A;
  A.map(data);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split your tensor class into two classes.

A tensor view, and a  tensor instance.

The instance can be converted to a view, but views cannot he converted to instances.

Now, views themselves can be split into two different kinds; slices or spans are observers.  Slices can be used to edit element data in the source of their element data, observers cannot.  You may not need slices, and you should write observers first.

Once you have these types, you can make algorithms that only take the type you need in the algorithm. It is very rarely a full tensor instance.

You do have to carefully manage lifetime of everything viewed. If you find this hard and cannot easily get better at it (and it is hard, entire languages have been written with a 2-3x performance slowdown simply to avoid having to solve this problem manually), you can modify your view types to require shared ownership of the array data, and store all tensor data on the heap in shared pointers. This has costs.

Comment: Thanks for the response. If I'd spilt the two functionalities, which sounds reasonable, how would I be able to have functions accept both? I specifically want to avoid void pointers to enhance readability.

Comment: @tom instances implicitly convert to views.  Views are abstractions of references.

Comment: I see. One last thing... What is actually wrong with my approach? I.e. regardless of style, why is it that this class sometimes returns gibberish, suggesting that `m_container` has been freed?

Comment: @TomdeGeus You failed to follow the rule of 5.  Your constructor which makes one element point at another doesn't work with default copy/move/destroy default member functions.